# How to Python3 Import CSV Header to List

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, csv, import

I keep seeing examples on the internet on how to import all the CSV into List/Dict/Tuple but none showing how to just import the FIRST ROW i.e. Header columns into a list.

I have tried doing

```
import csv
filename = "Example.csv"

columnHeaderList

with open(filename,'r') as data:
    for line in csv.reader(data): 
        columnHeaderList.append(line)
        break

columnHeaderList
```

which gave a nested list like below:

```
[0,
 ['Column 1',
  'Column 2',
  'Column 3']]
```

How do I get it like :

```
['Column 1', 'Column 2','Column 3']
```

Feel free to include answers in **pandas** also

Comment: Try `columnHeaderList = line`.  (And this code cannot produce the claimed output, since `headerColumnList` is never initialized.)

Comment: Doing that printed out the last row in the CSV list not the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly open your file:-

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Example.csv")
```

**Note:-** by default seperator is `','` if you have other seperator then pass `sep` parameter in `read_csv()` method

just use this:-

```
df.columns.to_list()
```

Comment: Thanks - it worked! So the keyword to google is Series.to_list()